# Excel VBA setting a default value from a custom function only once

Tags: excel, vba

I want to set the default value of a cell to the results of a custom function.

Once the cell has it's value it must never change.

How can I either:

- Test if the calling cell has a value? from what I've seen if you test `Application.Caller.Value` it re-evaluates the cell calling the function again. 
  I've tried passing the current value in but it goes all circular `=myFunc(A1)`.
- Immediately remove the function once the value has been set. I've tried `Cell.Value = Cell.Value` but it just calls the function again.
- Lock the cell, or make it `read-only`, add some sort of never calculate me again flag.

to recreate the problem - 
set a bunch of cells to `=NOW()` then wait for a moment and do a different cell and you'll notice all cells update to now, I want my function to run only once.

all input gratefully received

Comment: You will not be able to achieve what you're trying to do via a user-defined function. You should take a look at `Worksheet_Change` events. These will let you check if a cell that has been changed contains a particular value and then lock the cell or anything else you wish to do with the cell.

Answer (score 0):

jaybus, talk about rubber duck.

```
Public Function SetOnce() As String

Application.Caller.Clear
SetOnce = Rnd(100)

End Function


edit: ok this kind of works, but the function remains
```

Comment: is this the solution to your question?

Comment: well it works, but it leaves the function, however it never gets called again unless i go into the bar and hit return. im going to try your suggestion before marking it

Answer (score 0):

not so sure about your exact goal, but you may try to put this in the relevant worksheet code pane:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If InStr(Target.Formula, "MyFunc") > 0 Then ' change "MyFunc" tou your actual function name
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Calculation = XlCalculation.xlCalculationManual
        Target.Value = Target.Value
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.Calculation = XlCalculation.xlCalculationAutomatic
    End If
End Sub
```